# beforeActivate not firing jeasyui

Tags: tabs, jquery-easyui

I've read through many of these questions and they are answered the same.  I've tried it but can't get it to work.  I've gotten the code very small.  What am I doing wrong?  The tabs work fine, but no event getting fired.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">    
      $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#tabs').tabs({
          beforeActivate: function(event,ui) {
            alert("Tabs Changed");
          }
       });
      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="easyui-tabs" id="tabs">         
      <div Title="Home" >
        Home
      </div>
      <div Title="Admin">     
        Admin
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

thanks,
dave

Comment: I've never used this plugin, however I cannot seem to find any reference to a `beforeActivate` event for tabs. I'm looking here: http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/tabs.php. Is it possible you've mixed up events for different plugins (or am I looking in the wrong place)?

Comment: Well now I feel dumb. I got it confused with the jqueryui instead of jeasyui.  Using onSelect from your link works fine. thanks